# Vector of pointer to member functions

Tags: c++, vector, function-pointers

I'm trying to write a program which creates a class that contains *vector* of pointers to member functions, with `add()` and `remove()` member functions.
The code I wrote is -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

typedef void(*classFuncPtr)();

class FunctionVectors
{
private:
   vector<classFuncPtr> FunctionPointerVector;
 public:
   FunctionVectors(){}
   void add(classFuncPtr funcPtr);
   void remove(int index);
   void run();
   void a(){cout<<"a: Why are you calling me?"<<endl;}
 };
 
 void FunctionVectors::add(classFuncPtr funcPtr)
 {
   FunctionPointerVector.push_back(funcPtr);
 }
 
 void FunctionVectors::remove(int index)
 {
   FunctionPointerVector.erase(FunctionPointerVector.begin() + index);
 }
 
int main()
{
   FunctionVectors f;
   classFuncPtr fv = &(classFuncPtr)FunctionVectors::a;  // error here
  
   f.add(fv);
   f.run();
  
   return 0;
}
```

But, it is showing error in line# 32 -

```
error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall FunctionVectors::* )(void)' to 'classFuncPtr'
```

Please, tell me how should I modify it to work properly.

Comment: I suggest you to use std::function instead of raw function pointers (boost::function if you are not allowed to use c++11)

Comment: Take a look at `std::mem_fn`.

Comment: If you want to store a pointer to a member function, then you'll need a [pointer to member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions), not a plain function pointer. But a more generic type like [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) would  probably be easier to deal with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
typedef void(*classFuncPtr)();
```

This is not a pointer to method, but a pointer to function. Method differs from function, because it's being called in a context: requires `this` to work correctly.

Keep in mind, that in C++ you are only able to create vector of pointers to a method of specific class. So you won't be able to keep pointers to two methods of different classes in that vector.

The solution - as suggested in comments - is to use `std::function` or `boost::function` and possibly C++11 lambdas, because they provide a lot more flexibility than simple pointer-to-members.

If you want to implement an event mechanism, consider also using functors instead of methods:

1. Create base class for event handler:

   ```
   class MyEventHandler
   {
   public:
       virtual void operator()(void * sender, int data) = 0;
   }
   ```
2. Create simple vector of these:

   ```
   std::vector<MyEventHandler *> MyEvent;
   ```
3. Create specific handlers in your classes:

   ```
   class MyClass
   {
   private:
       class SpecificEventHandler : MyEventHandler
       {
       public:
           void operator()(void * sender, int data)
           {
               std::cout << "Event handled!";
           }
       }

   public:
       SpecificEventHandler Handler;

       MyClass()
       {
       }
   }
   ```
4. Hook the handler to your event:

   ```
   MyEvent.push_back(&(myClassInstance.Handler));
   ```

Code written from memory, may not compile, but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::function< void() >
```

looks like the signature you are looking for. If it isn't available in your version of C++ but you can use boost, then you fill find it in boost. Look up documentation for appropriate header,  for std,  for function.

To create one for a member function, you need to bind it, and to bind it to `FunctionVectors::a()` you will need an instance of a `FunctionVectors` to call it on.

In your example, I will make the typedef for you

typedef std::function< void() > classFuncPtr; // in reality a badly named typedef

int main()
   {
       FunctionVectors f;
       classFuncPtr fv = std::bind( &FunctionVectors::a, f );
   }

alternatively if you really have C++11 with lambdas you can do

```
   classFuncPtr = [ f ]() { f.a() );
```

In your case I reckon you don't really want a free function, you always want a member function of your class you want.

```
   typedef void (*FunctionVectors::classFuncPtr )();
```

and you would use

```
    (this->*func)();
```

to invoke it

Comment: Neither gcc nor clang likes `this(->*func)();`. They are only happy with even more parentheses: `(this(->*func))();` .

Comment: yeah I moved the opening parenthesis